# When does I/O redirection occur relative to the execution of commands in the Linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell, find

On my desktop, there is only one file,its name is "file1.txt",then I execute shell script like this:

```
$ find . -name "*.txt" > file2.txt
```

After that, I run the other shell script like this:

```
$ cat file2.txt
```

Its output is:

```
./file1.txt
./file2.txt
```

So it looks like that the execution of `find` command is behind the creat of file “file2.txt"， Am I right?

Comment: Your first command's output was directed into `file2.txt`. That output was `file1.txt`, so all is correct. I think you need to read about `>` in linux (i.e. stream redirecting)

Answer (score 3):

You are correct; the I/O redirection takes place before the `find` command is executed, so the file `file2.txt` already exists (but is empty) when the `find` command is running.  Therefore, the output of the `find` command will include `file2.txt`.

It makes sense if you think about it.  The redirection has to be done before `find` executes.  You can't have it writing to the terminal first and then going to the file, even if there was a mechanism that allowed that.

Comment: And a corollary to be aware of is that, if for some reason a redirection fails, the command will never be run at all...

Answer (score 2):

You are right: the shell `open`s the output file first, creating it. Then it creates a subprocess with `fork`. The shell then closes the file and waits for the child to return. The child process calls `dup` or `dup2` to open the output file with file descriptor 1, and only then it executes the command with one of the functions of the `exec` family.